# Why can't i convert from string to integer here?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, integer

The code is:

```
public static bool IsValidIp(string ipAddres)
{
  string[] sNumbers = ipAddres.Split('.');
  int[] iNumbers = new int[sNumbers.Length];

  for(int i = 0; sNumbers.Length > i; i++){
    iNumbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sNumbers[i]);
  }

  return 255 >= iNumbers.Max();
}
```

The error:

```
System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I tried with several inputs like: "0.0.0.0", "12.255.56.1", "137.255.156.100".
It keeps throwing back the same error message.

Comment: Suggested reading: [IPAddress.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-7.0),

Comment: Is your `for` loop correct?

Comment: I think it was correct, but I rewrote the program with The Unstoppable's method and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [Convert.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32), [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) might be a better solution, as it checks if input is valid before doing the conversion.

```cs
if (int.TryParse(sNumbers[i], out int result))
{
   iNumbers[i] = result;
}
else 
{
   return false;
}
```

However, I think you are trying to validate if specified argument is a valid IP address or not. Using [IPAddress.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse) method instead would be a better practice.

```cs
using System.Net;
// ...

public static bool IsValidIp(string address)
{
   return IPAddress.TryParse(address, out var _);
}
```

`out var _` discards the value as it is not used.